# android version required

Tags: android, version, publishing

I have created and published an application on the market...
However, on the market page it says: "Version required 1.0" while I know it needs at least version 2.0 (level 8) as it uses google maps..

I know that I have to include in the manifest file something like this:

I have tried to change the number 1 for another, but if I do it, the app crashes straight away with the following message:

*android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #154: Error inflating class*

Has anybody came across something similar?

Thanks

Comment: "I know it needs at least version 2.0 (level 8) as it uses google maps" -- Google Maps has existed since Android 1.0, and even before that.

Answer (score 1):

In your AndroidManifest.xml file, you need to include `android:minSdkVersion` and `<uses-sdk>` element. For example, I have this in my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:minSdkVersion="4"
    ...
>
    ...
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" android:targetSdkVersion="7"/>
    ...
</manifest>
```

Have a look here for more details: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html